# ElasticSearch / Tire - Facets are not filtered by the query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have an ElasticSearch / Tire query that has facets attached. It seems the facets a using the global scope, instead of the query scope and filters.

Here is my definition. I'm not sure how to scope the it to use the filters.

```
 def self.facets_for(keyword_array, fasit, opts = {})
    keyword_array = [keyword_array] if keyword_array.is_a?(String)
    tire.search(per_page: opts[:per_page], page: opts[:page] ) do 
      query do 
        boolean { should { string '*' }}
      end
      filter :terms, :keyword => keyword_array

      facet "phrases" do terms :phrases, :size => 20 end if fasit.include?("phrases")
      facet "sentiment" do terms :sentiment end if fasit.include?("sentiment")
      facet "lang" do terms :lang end if fasit.include?("lang")
      facet "provider" do terms :provider end if fasit.include?("provider")

    end # tire search
  end
```

Right now, this returns facets that are "global" in scope, i.e. they aren't filtered by the filters (or the query if there is a more sophisticated query).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facets *are* by default bound (restricted) by the query issued: see the [Tire integration test case](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/facets_test.rb#L11-L23).

Filters, on the contrary, do *not* restrict the facets, making "faceted navigation" possible (again, see the [integration test case](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/master/test/integration/filters_test.rb#L59-L69)).

Note that in your example, your query is effectively a `match_all` query, and thus cannot restrict facets.

---

On the Ruby side of things, a safer construct for `keyword_array` would be:

```
keyword_array = Array(keyword_array)
```